# In what sense is the verb "begeben" intended in the song Schifoan by Wolfgang Ambros?

Tags: translation, german-to-english, austrian

The lyrics of "Schifoan" by Wolfgang Ambros include this snippet:

> Am Freitog auf'd Nocht montier' i die Schi
> Auf mei' Auto und dann begib' i mi
> In's Stubaitoi oder noch Zöll am See
> Weu, durt auf die Berg ob'm
> Ham's immer an leiwand'n Schnee!

A standard German translation (from the Viennese dialect) given [here](https://www.songtexte.com/uebersetzung/wolfgang-ambros/schifoan-deutsch-3bd6804c.html) says:

> Am Freitagabend montier ich die Ski
> Auf mein Auto und dann begebe ich mich
> Ins Stubaital oder nach Zell am See,
> Denn dort auf den Bergen oben
> Gibt es immer einen supertollen Schnee!

I've always understood [begeben](https://en.langenscheidt.com/german-english/begeben) to mean to leave for a destination or to waive a choice. What's a better translation of the line into English?

> On Friday evening, I mount the skis on my car and then I must decide:
> to Stubaital or to Zell am See

or

> On Friday evening, I mount the skis on my car and then I go to
> Stubaital or to Zell am See...

Or is there a another way to say it, which is better still?

Comment: Anecdotically, I once talked to an englishman who wanted to *migrate* to the pub, before doing something. Auf Deutsch I'd say *er begibt sich in den pub*

Comment: There is nothing like an *»Austrian Dialekt«.* There is Austrian Standard German (Österreichisches Deutsch), Austrian Colloquial German (österreichische Umgangssprache) and there is a continuum of many local dialects, of which the majority belongs to the group of Bavarian dialects. Wolfgang Ambros was born and socialized in Vienna. He wrote the lyrics of Schifoan, but many other lyrics of his songs were written by Joesi Prokopetz, who also was born and socialized in Vienna. So all songs of Wolfgang Ambros are in Viennese Dialect. (I corrected this in your posting)

Comment: ... The adjective *leiwand* was unknown in Stubaital and Zell am See and the rest of Austria before Ambros published *Schifoan* in December 1976. It was used only in the metropol region Vienna (Vienna and neighboring urban areas). Without this song the word *leuwand* still would be completely unknown outside of Vienna. Nobody outside of Vienna uses this adjective actively. And this word is dying. It will have become extinct in a few decades. Only people older than 50 years use it today and it is limited to working class people (it never was used in high society).

Comment: @HubertSchölnast: I consider *Austrian dialect* as a legal shortening of *one of the dialects spoken in Austria* and the dialect might even vary between more remote districts of Vienna.

Comment: @guidot: So, you would say, that the songs performed by the Kölschrock band BAP are sung in German dialect?

Comment: @guidot: So, if someone asks you, "Hey, this Kölschrock band BAP, in which language do they sing their songs?" will you answer, "Well, they sing in German dialect."? I don't think so.

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Well, of course Kölsch is German dialect.

Comment: @tofro: Well, I would not answer *»they sing in German dialect«* because this sounds as if there was only one dialect in Germany (like it sounds like there was only one Austrian Dialect when you say that "Schifoan" is in Austrian Dialect). My answer would be *»they sing in Kölsch, this is the dialect of Cologne.«*

Comment: @HubertSchölnast Das kann man al "pars pro toto" sehen, wie in "Das deutsche Auto kommt aus der Mode" - und nein, in Deutschland gibt es mehr als ein Auto.

Comment: @tofro: Da stand [*»from **the** Austrian dialect«.*](https://german.stackexchange.com/revisions/69782/1) Und das, was da nach dem bestimmten Artikel stand, nämlich **den** österreichischen Dialekt gibt es ganz bestimmt nicht. An *»from **an** Austrian dialect«* hätte ich nichts auszusetzen gehabt, denn es ist richtig, dass Schifoan in **einem** österreichischen Dialekt geschrieben ist, aber es ist nicht in **dem** österreichischen Dialekt geschrieben, weil es den nun mal nicht gibt.

Answer (score 3):

"Sich an einen Ort begeben" means "to go somewhere", "to resort to a place".

[DWDS](https://www.dwds.de/wb/begeben) calls the expression "papierdeutsch" ("paper German"), it's quite formal, and it's a probably intentionally out-of-place expression in that song.

Some examples that show the typical habitat of the expression:

> Nach dem Essen begab sich die Gesellschaft in den Ballsaal. *(After dinner, the company proceeded to the ballroom.)*

> Die Gräfin verabschiedete sich von ihren Gästen und begab sich in ihre Gemächer. *(The Countess said goodbye to her guests and retired to her chambers.)*

> Bitte begeben Sie sich nach Ihrer Ankunft auf die Abflugebene zum Terminal B. *(After your arrival, please proceed to the departure level to Terminal B.)*

More examples with translations:
[Bitte begeben Sie sich ...](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/uebersetzung/bitte+begeben+sie+sich.html);
[sich+begeben](https://www.linguee.de/deutsch-englisch/search?source=auto&query=sich%20begeben)

Comment: Right, it breaks with the style of the rest of the lyrics. I have always understood it as a bit self-ironic, given the proletarian habitus he is depicting.

Comment: I suspect, that for the meter two syllables were desired.

Answer (score 1):

### sich begeben

The verb *begeben,* as used here, is a reflexive verb. This means, you always must use it with a reflexive pronoun:

> Clara **begibt sich** in die Küche.
> Clara **moves/goes/runs/saunters/jumps/crawls/dances/...** into the kitchen.

- sich an einen Ort begeben = to move to a place

*Sich begeben* is a verb of movement like *gehen* (go, walk), laufen (run), schlendern (saunter), hüpfen (jump), kriechen (crawl), tanzen (dance), fahren (drive), reiten (ride), schwimmen (swimm), fliegen (fly) and many more. But *sich begeben* is still different. It describes a movement, but it does not describe the kind of movement. It just describes that you change your spatial position, but it leaves it completely open how this change is performed.

*Sich begeben* can mean that you walk, it can mean that you fly, it can mean that you use the bus, it can mean that you dig a tunnel and crawl through it. It can mean any kind of movement.

So, if you want to tell that you travel to the location X, but if you don't want to tell if you walk or drive or ride or what ever, then you can say

> Ich begebe mich morgen nach Linz.
> I'm off to Linz tomorrow.

And I disagree with HalvarF's claim that *sich begeben* is *Papierdeutsch.* At least in Austria it still is a productive verb. It is part of Austrian Standard German, and it is used in colloquial speech in Austria. But it is rare in dialects spoken in Austria, and this is what gives it the displaced character in Ambros's song. It is a little bit out-of-place in this song not because it is *»Papierdeutsch«* but because it is a non-dialect verb in a dialect context.

Here are examples of its usage:

> Erzbischof Franz Lackner hat **sich** nach positiver Testung zweier Personen in seinem Umfeld in Selbstisolation **begeben**
> <sup>[meinbezirk.at](https://www.meinbezirk.at/salzburg/c-lokales/erzbischof-lackner-als-kontaktperson-im-homeoffice_a5022520) 2021-11-22 Austrian newspaper (each political district has it's own issue of *meinbezirk,* so it's a local newspaper)</sup>
>
> Startrainer Pep Guardiola vom englischen Fußballmeister Manchester City hat **sich** nach einem positiven Corona-Test in Isolation **begeben.**
> <sup>[DiePresse.at](https://www.diepresse.com/6082296/pep-guardiola-in-isolation-nach-21-verdachtsfaellen-bei-mancity) 2022-01-06 Austrian newspaper, published in Vienna, for all of Austria</sup>
>
> Spendenaffäre: "Mayr hat **sich** auf Glatteis **begeben**"
> <sup>[kurier.at](https://kurier.at/chronik/oesterreich/hubert-sickinger-zur-salzburger-spendenaffaere-hans-mayr-hat-sich-auf-glatteis-begeben/303.175.250) 2017-12-22 Austrian newspaper, similar status as DiePresse</sup>
>
> Hat **sich** schon in Startposition **begeben**
> <sup>[meinbezirk.at](https://www.meinbezirk.at/landstrasse/imagepost/hat-sich-schon-in-startposition-begeben_i50277) 2019-02-07</sup>
>
> Die Autoindustrie hat **sich** in eine gefährliche Abhängigkeit **begeben**
> <sup>[sueddeutsche.de](https://www.sueddeutsche.de/wirtschaft/autoindustrie-china-risiko-1.5487871) 2021-12-15 high quality national German newspaper, published in Munich(Bavaria)</sup>
>
> Wie **sich** Jugendliche via Smartphone auf Identitätssuche **begeben**
> <sup>[DiePresse.at](https://www.diepresse.com/5467696/wie-sich-jugendliche-via-smartphone-auf-identitaetssuche-begeben) 2018-07-20</sup>
>
> **Begeben Sie sich** auf die Pirsch durch die Wälder des Naturparks
> <sup>[tierpark.at](https://www.tierpark.at/index.php/3d-bogenparcour/145-3d-bogenparcour-buchenberg-begeben-sie-sich-auf-die-pirsch-durch-die-waelder-des-naturparks) (no date) Website of an Austrian adventure park and zoo</sup>
>
> ichkoche.at hat **sich** unter die Experimental-Köche **begeben**
> <sup>[ichkoche.at](https://www.ichkoche.at/mythos-1-tomaten-schaelen-artikel-3950) (no date) Austrian cooking site</sup>
>
> Forscher **begeben sich** auf einen Streifzug durch die Geistesgeschichte
> <sup>[DerStandard.at](https://www.derstandard.at/story/2000061146582/die-geburt-der-expertenkultur) 2017-07-15 Austrian newspaper, similar status as DiePresse and Kurier</sup>
>
> Eine dreiköpfige Familie hat **sich** im Harz auf den Brocken **begeben.**
> <sup>[RND.de](https://www.rnd.de/panorama/trotz-sturm-auf-dem-brocken-familie-will-warnungen-nicht-bemerkt-haben-43VZQCG63NE3HMAHV4PS6K2YGQ.html) 2022-02-12 German editorial network (Hannover, Berlin)</sup>

As you can see, from 10 sources that I found, 8 are from Austria, 1 from Bavaria and 1 from northern parts of Germany. This makes me believe, that *»sich begeben«* is mainly used in southern regions. If it is *»Papierdeutsch«* then only in northern parts of Germany.

---

### etwas begeben

Note, that there is also a transitive version of *begeben* which has a very different meaning:

> Nur juristische Personen können **Anleihen begeben.**
> Only legal entities can **issue bonds.**

- etwas begeben = to issue something
  the *something* are bonds, shares and similar financial products

---

Off topic:

Let me also add something to the Standard German translation of the Lyrics:
A better translation into standard German would be:

> ... weu durt auf die Berg om **hom's** imma an leiwondn Schnee
> ... denn dort auf den Bergen oben **haben sie** immer einen tollen Schnee

Standard German *»gibt es«* (*there is*) would be *»gibt's«* in Viennese dialect. Ambros could have sung *»gibt's«* but he didn't. He sang *»hom's«* which is Standard German *»haben sie«* and English *»they have«.* This is a different meaning.

The English translation of this snippet is:

> On Friday evening I mount the skis
> on my car and then I go
> to the Stubaital or to Zell am See.
> Because up there on the mountains
> **they** always **have** a great snow!

Comment: I'm not really sure what DWDS means by their attribute "papierdeutsch", I don't think they mean to say that it isn't used any more. I agree with you that it is definely used, just not so much in oral language.

Comment: "Papier" like in "Monopoly" - *Gehe in das Gefängnis. Begib Dich direkt dorthin. Gehe nicht über Los. Ziehe nicht DM 4000 ein*

Comment: "Sich begeben" has one more meaning not related to moving somewhere.  "Es begab sich aber zu der Zeit, dass ein Gebot von dem Kaiser Augustus ausging ... "